# How can I crop my slider image in my existing wordpress site?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I could not able to crop my slider image properly.

This is my image's inline style:

```
<img width="250" height="169" alt="Photo: Terrence Jones for Social Magazine Stylist: Lee Stalcup" src="http://revolverboutique.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/R8-278200_600x400.jpg" style="display: inline-block; width: 250px; height: 169px;">
```

This is also my stylesheet css in div:

```
#featured .slide img {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Set you `height` to `auto` in your stylesheet

Comment: did hight:auto; but not fixed @OneKitten

Comment: You mean @PieterGoosen? I didn't suggest to use `height: auto;`.

Comment: This is my site [link](http://revolverboutique.com/) where I faced the problem . Its urgent to fix the probplem. @OneKitten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add "px" in when changing the width and height.

```
width="250px" height="169px"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4777z/

Comment: If i use px after that it is not fixed @Jonathan Wexler

Comment: Are you trying to resize the image? or crop a portion of it?

Comment: yes, I was trying. This is my orginal image http://revolverboutique.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/R8.jpg  . But when it cropped please take a look the image's head is cut off. @jonathan-wexler

Answer (score 0):

This is going to resize the images in your browser, which is slower and not really ideal. If you have a fixed width (250 x 169, for instance) and want to show all images in that slider with that fixed width, you'd be better off creating a custom thumbnail size (eg https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) and using the appropriate image size in your slider (many sliders are handled with plugins, and most that I've seen allow you to select which thumbnail size to use. Depending on your slider, that may be different for you. But the basic premise that it's better to resize the image on the server and have the slider serve an already scaled image still applies)

If you guy this route, make sure you regenerate your thumbnails after you add the new image size.